# GDB prints different values while running

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm new with gdb and I don't understand the values given to the output. I've been testing some toy program just to learn the behaviour.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    bool arr[2] = {true, false};
    printf("Value at index 2 of array is %d\n", arr[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

As we can observe, the trick at the buggy program is in `arr[2]` where we can expect some `NULL`. But when I compile it gives:

```
$ ./a.exe
Value at index 2 of array is 130
```

However with gdb the behaviour looks pretty different:

```
$ gdb a.exe
(gdb) b main
(gdb) run

Thread 1 "a" hit Breakpoint 1, main () at table.c:5
5           bool arr[2] = {true, false};
(gdb) p arr
$1 = {34, false}
(gdb) p arr[2]
$2 = 211
```

Where is the returned value of 130 given by `a.exe`? Why 130? Why 211? And I absolutely didn't understand `$1 = {34, false}`. I've compiled with `-g` flag. It means: `gcc -g buggy.c`

My gcc version compiler gives this: **gcc (GCC) 9.3.0**

GDB Version: **GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 9.2-1) 9.2**

My OS runs: **Windows 7 Professional i686**

Working on: **Cygwin setup version 2.905 (32 bit)**

Comment: When a breakpoint is hit and gdb shows you a line of code, the program has stopped *before* that line of code has executed. So at line 5, `bool arr[2] = {true, false};`, the assignment of those values to the array hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arr` only has 2 elements, accessing `arr[2]` amounts to accessing the third element of the array, wich does not exist, this invokes undefined behavior, as a consequence, no consistent behavior is to be expected from this program.

[ISO/IEC 9899:201x - §3.4.3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3)

> 1. undefined behavior
>
> Behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,for which this International Standard imposes no requirements.
>
> 2. NOTE
>
> Possible  undefined  behavior  ranges  from  ignoring  the  situation  completely  with  unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment  (with  or  without  the  issuance  of  a  diagnostic  message), to  terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

`$1 = {34, false}` is the likely result of you printing the array before it's initialized, setting the breakpoint in the next line should give you the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have any array bound checks in the language <sup>(1)</sup>, so if you index off the end of an array you'll get undefined behavior which means the compiler is free to do whatever it finds convenient.

In practice this means it will access whatever memory would have been used if the array had been bigger, running one past the allocated memory for the array into memory that's already used for something else.

You've not set any value into that memory in your program so it will return whatever value just happens to be in that memory.

When you run under a debugger you move things around in memory and the computer runs things a little differently so there is no reason to expect that the value will be the same as a normal run. It may differ every time you run the program anyway!

(1) some library functions such as `vector::at` have bounds checks and some compilers offer it as an extension but the core language doesn't define any.